# Como coletar 'data-userid' de um Button gerado por Ajax e utilizar o 'data-userid' em um post?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estou com dificuldades na seguinte situação:

Eu tenho duas páginas: **radioPage.php** e **radioPageBD.php.**

Na **radioPage.php** o usuário poderá selecionar o `RadioButton` Empresa ou o `RadioButton` cliente. Os dois fazem consultas diferentes no banco de dados, um trará a relação de empresas e o outro de clientes.

A distinção das consultas é feita por **ajax**, quando o usuário selecionar o rb Cliente, será enviado o valor 1 de uma variável JavaScript (`var_query`) para uma variável em php (`idQuery`).

Se o valor for 1, executa a query para listar as empresas. Se o valor for 2, executa a query para listar os clientes. Quando um dos rb's é selecionado, o conteúdo é enviado para a `div` `buttons_CE`.

Essa passagem de variável do Javascript para o php é feita na própria **radioPage.php**

Ele traz essas relações de empresas/clientes recursivamente em buttons. Acompanhe o print a seguir:

[image: Empresa_Cliente]

Quando o usuário clicar em algum desses `Button`'s, deverá ser feito um post para a página **radioPageBD.php** onde ela irá retornar um html para a `div` `#resultadofinal` contendo as informações da empresa.

Para todos os `Button`'s, existe uma espécie de id que se chama `data-userid`. Nesse `data-userid` é gravado o código da empresa, para que a **radioPageBD.php** consiga fazer a consulta de informações da empresa pelo código (`CDEMPRESA`).

**A minha dúvida é: Porque eu não estou conseguindo passar o data-userid para o post e listar as informações da empresa?**

Atualmente na radioPage.php eu tenho um Post já pronto. Acompanhe os fontes a seguir:

**radioPage.php**

```
<?php 

include('radioPageBD.php');

/* 
*  Se o idQuery possuir dados então o switchQuery recebe o idQuery. Se o switchQuery = 1 então ele faz uma consulta listando as empresas
*  Se o switchQuery = 2 então ele faz uma consulta listando os cliente.   
*/

if(isset($_GET['idQuery'])){

        $switchQuery = $_GET['idQuery'];
        if($switchQuery == 1){
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM EMPRESA");

                 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { ?>

                <button class="doQuery" data-userid="<?php echo($row['CDEMPRESA']); ?>"> <?php echo($row['DSNOMEFANTASIA']); ?></button><br>
<?php } 

        }
        else if($switchQuery == 2){ 
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CLIENTE");

                 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ ?>

                <button class="doQuery" data-userid="<?php echo($row['CDEMPRESA']); ?>"><?php echo($row['DSCLIENTE']); ?></button><br>
<?php 
                }
        }
}
else {

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="radio" name="rd1" class="radio" id="rd1" nm-radio="1">Empresa</input>
        <input type="radio" name="rd1" class="radio" id="rd2" nm-radio="2">Cliente</input>

        <div id="buttons_CE"></div>
        <div id="resultadofinal"> </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>

$(function(){   
    $.system = {};
    $.system.path = '/teste/'; // ou colocar a pasta raiz $.system.path = '/';

    /*Ao clicar nos botões "doQuery" ele atribui o valor do data-userid para o id_usuario e envia este valor para a radioPageBD.php*/

    jQuery(".doQuery").click(function(){

        var id_usuario = $(this).attr('data-userid');

        jQuery.post( $.system.path + 'radioPageBD.php' , { id_usuario:id_usuario,outraval:'valor_da_val' } , function(result,status){ 


            if( status == 'success' ){

                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

                if( json.resultStatus == 'success' ){
                    jQuery("#resultadofinal").html(json.html);
                }
                else{
                    jQuery("#resultadofinal").html(json.resultMSG);

                }

            } 
            else{
                alert('Erro na requisicao jquery');
            }


        });
    });

    /*Se o radioButton rd1 estiver selecionado, ele envia o valor 1 para a variável idQuery nesta mesma página. Se o radioButton rd2 estiver selecionado, ele envia o valor 2 para a variável idQuery.*/

    $(".radio").change(function(){


                if(document.getElementById("rd1").checked){
                var var_query = 1;

                        $.ajax({
                        url: 'radioPage.php',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: { idQuery: var_query },
                        success: function(data) {

                            $('#buttons_CE').html(data);
                         }

                        });

                 }
                else if (document.getElementById("rd2").checked){
                    var var_query = 2;

                        $.ajax({
                        url: 'radioPage.php',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: { idQuery: var_query },
                        success: function(data) {

                            $('#buttons_CE').html(data);
                         }
                    });
            }       
    });

}); 
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

---

**radioPageBD.php**

```
<?php 

    $con   = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    $db    = mysql_select_db('telefones',$con);

    /* Aqui ele captura o data-userid da radioPage.php e faz uma consulta no banco de dados filtrando por esse código. */
    if( isset($_POST['id_usuario'])){

        // input    
        $id    = $_POST['id_usuario'];


        $html  = array();

        //Query a ser executada
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM EMPRESA E WHERE E.CDEMPRESA = '{$id}'",$con);

        if(mysql_error()){
            $html['resultStatus'] = 'error';    
            $html['resultMSG']    = mysql_error();
        } 
        else{

            if( mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 1 ){

                $html['resultStatus'] = 'success';      

                /*Quando a consulta retorna algum resultado, é enviado o HTML abaixo contendo as informações da empresa para a div resultadofinal na radioPage.php; */


                while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ){
                    //HTML responsável por exibir cada as informações da empresa ou do cliente. Ele passa esse HTML para a div resultadofinal.

                    $html['html'] = "

                    <label for='razaoSocial'>Razão Social:</label> 
                    <input type='text' id='razaoSocial' style='width: 300px;' value='{$row['DSRAZAOSOCIAL']}' readonly='readonly'></input>
                        <label for='nmtelefone' style='margin-left: 127px;'>Telefone:</label> 
                        <input type='text' id='nmtelefone' value='{$row['NMTELEFONE']}' readonly='readonly'></input>
                            <label for='UF' style='margin-left: 130px;'>UF: </label>
                            <input type='text' id='UF' style='width: 30px;' value='{$row['DSUF']}' readonly='readonly'></input>
                                    <br><br>
                                    <p><label for='dsusuario'>Usuário</label> 
                                    <input type='text' id='dsusuario' value='{$row['DSUSUARIO']}' readonly='readonly'></input>
                                <label for='dssenha'>Senha:</senha>
                                <input type='text' id='dssenha' value='{$row['DSSENHA']}' readonly='readonly'></input>

                            <label for='dsgestumlic'>Gestum:</label> 
                            <input type='text' id='dsgestumlic' style='width: 100px;' value='{$row['DSGESTUMLIC']}' readonly='readonly'></input>
                       <label for='nmlic'>Nº Licenças:</label>
                       <input type='text' id='nmlic' style='margin-left: width: 30px;' value='{$row['NMLIC']}' readonly='readonly'></input></p>
                        <br><br><br>
                <label for='dsobs'>OBS:</label>
                <p><textarea id='dsobs' style='max-width:955px; width: 955px; resize: vertical; ' readonly='readonly'>{$row['DSOBS']}</textarea></p>

                    ";
                }
            }
            else{
                $html['resultStatus'] = 'error';        
                $html['resultMSG'] = 'Nenhum resultado';                    
            }
        }
        // output
        echo json_encode($html);
    }

?>
```

> Apenas ressaltando que tanto para os buttons de empresa e cliente, ao
>   clicar em um deles será listado as informações da empresa. Na tabela
>   dos clientes existe uma FK onde é referenciado a empresa para o
>   cliente. Então, se eu consultar por cliente e clicar em algum, será
>   feita a consulta pela FK CDEMPRESA desse cliente.

Conto com a ajuda de vocês, obrigado!

Comment: Testa `jQuery(document).on('click', ".doQuery", function(){` em vêz de `jQuery(".doQuery").click(function(){`. Isso resolve o problema?

Comment: dá uma olhada em `$(document).delegate('.doQuery', 'click', function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery disponibiliza a função [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) para buscar os atributos `data-*`.

No seu código altere

```
var id_usuario = $(this).attr('data-userid');
```

Para

```
var id_usuario = $(this).data('userid');
```

outro erro que pode estar afetando o resultado esperado: o *loop* que cria os `<button>` está antes do `<html>`, o correto é ser colocado dentro do `<body>`.

---

Leitura recomendada: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4675/13561)